# May a compactly supported real-valued function cross $0$ in its support finitely many times?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness

This may be an obvious question for many, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is right.

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a compact supported function, here, this means that the set $supp(f):= \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \neq 0\}}$ is compact on $\mathbb{R}$.

Every example I've seen for a compact supported function is a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), but I think it could be a function also like the one in this image.

[image]

So, $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} sin\left(2\pi x\right) & \text{if} & x \in (0,2)\\
0 & \text{if} & x \in (-\infty,0]\\
0 & \text{if} & x \in [2,\infty)\\\end{matrix} \right.$$

We have that
\begin{align}
supp(f)& := \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \neq 0\}}\\
&  = \overline{(0,0.5) \cup (0.5,1) \cup (1,1.5) \cup (1.5,2)}\\ 
& = \overline{(0,0.5)} \cup \overline{(0.5,1)} \cup \overline{(1,1.5)} \cup \overline{(1.5,2)}\\
&  = [0,0.5] \cup [0.5,1] \cup [1,1.5] \cup [1.5,2]
\end{align}

Which is compact.

Is my reasoning right or am I missing something important?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this question is duped.

Comment: Yes, the example you've given is compactly supported.

Comment: Thanks, I was having doubts because every example I've seen for a compact supported function is a bump function, should I delete my question?

Comment: You can even go a step further than the title suggests; a compactly supported function can have infinite or even uncountable zeroes within its support. E.g. $f(x) = 1$ when $x\in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @EliJohnson I see, thanks!!!

Comment: @CésarVB are you sure those aren't impicitly also examples of $C_c^\infty$?

Comment: @Andrew I'm sorry, are you suggesting that these functions I mention are all part of the set of bounded continuous with compact support?

Comment: I am saying that the bump functions are examples of $C_c^\infty$ functions, the existence of which is not a priori obvious. On the other hand, the existence of $C_c$ functions is obvious